# Why does this regular expression return incorrect values?

Tags: ruby, regex

Say I have a string as follows:

```
"auto: true; server: false;"
```

...and I want a regular expression to create a hash of these settings. I have the below code:

```
# class Configurer...
def spit(path = "", *args)
  spat = Hash.new
  if File.file?(path)
    # Parse file
  else
    args.each do |arg|
      begin
        if path.include? arg + ":"
          strip = path.match(/#{arg}:\s(.*);/)
          spat[arg] = strip[1]
        end
      rescue
        return "Error when parsing '#{arg}' in direct input."
      end
    end
  end
  spat
end
```

When something like:

```
config = Configurer.new
puts config.spit("auto: true; server: false;", "auto", "server")
```

...is ran, the output is an incorrect hash of:

```
# => {"auto"=>"true; server: false", "server"=>"false"}
```

Why is that? When I [parse a file (line by line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703826/why-does-this-only-return-the-first-setting) and use the same regular expression I get the desired hash. Why is this not the case with this method?

Comment: What if you set it to `strip[0]`?

Comment: @Linuxios If I did that it would return the original string, `1` is the second item in the `MatchData` array. That item is why the regular expression matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [non-greedy repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) instead:

```
/#{arg}:\s(.*?);/
```

Comment: Worked great! Do you think I should use it in the line-by-line parsing too? [Source code here](https://raw.github.com/RafalChmiel/configurer/master/configurer.rb).

Comment: It should make no difference there - as long as the value does not contain a semicolon. Maybe you should use it there only for the case that someone copies it to a place where it should match more than one key-value-pair…

Comment: or you could use `/([^;])*/`

Comment: @Rein: Yes, that's basically the same for this simple case. Maybe more expressive :-)

Comment: @Bergi Non-greedy is slightly slower as well but usually not significantly so. And anyway, if you're using regexp for speed then you're doing it wrong ;)